# Is there a built-in method to plot symmetric functions?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a symmetric function (odd/even), so I have to do something like:

```
plt.plot(np.concatenate([-x[::-1],x]),np.concatenate([y[::-1],y]))
```

Is there any easier way to do this, so I have to waste less memory?

Comment: Why not just plot two lines and style them the same?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just plot two lines:

```
def plot_odd(x,y, *args, **kwargs):
    plt.plot(x,y,*args,**kwargs)
    plt.plot(-x[::-1], -y[::-1], *args, **kwargs)

def plot_even(x,y, *args, **kwargs):
    plt.plot(x,y,*args,**kwargs)
    plt.plot(-x[::-1], y[::-1], *args, **kwargs)

x = np.linspace(0,6,100)
plot_odd(x, np.sin(x), 'b')
plot_even(x, np.cos(x), 'r')
plt.show()
```